# Add three string with separated commas and "and" value add

Tags: ios, string

i have Three TAG , tag1,tag2,tag3 its return from webservices 
and i want to display like **tag1,tag2 & tag3**  with commas  and  "&"word 
Here is my code

```
 NSString *tag1=[getSelectedArray valueForKey:@"tag1"];
 NSString *tag2=[getSelectedArray valueForKey:@"tag2"];
 NSString *tag3=[getSelectedArray valueForKey:@"tag3"];
 NSString *getTags; 
getTags=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ , %@ & %@",tag1,tag2,tag3];
```

The Problem is When tag1 and any other tag is null that time is look like 
**,tag2 & **
how to manage null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code,

```
NSString *getTags =(tag1 && tag2 && tag3)?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,%@ & %@",tag1,tag2,tag3]:(tag1 && tag2)?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,%@",tag1,tag2]:(tag1 && tag3)?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,%@",tag1,tag3]:(tag2 && tag3)?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ,%@",tag2,tag3]:tag1?tag1:tag2?tag2:tag3?tag3:@"";
```

Comment: one more problem when tag3 only null that time its show tag1,tag2 & please help me

Comment: I ran the code and it's give me output in this case tag1 & tag2.. can u clear your question? You want to say about when tag3 is nil only..

Comment: i want to if only tag1 have data and tag2,tag3 is null then print only tag1 , second condition is if any one tag have null then print like tag1 , tag2 and if three all tag have then look like tag1, tag2 & tag3

Comment: i edited my answer try to check it, may be it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Change all the Tag retrieval as:

```
NSString *tag1=[getSelectedArray valueForKey:@"tag1"] ? [getSelectedArray valueForKey:@"tag1"] : @"";
```

same for the other two tags.

*******EDIT******
In case your dictionary is returning an NSNUll object, you can do this:

```
NSString *tag1=[[getSelectedArray valueForKey:@"tag1"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ? [getSelectedArray valueForKey:@"tag1"] : @"";
```

Comment: Null is also acts as instance

Comment: Oh. U mean NSNull ?? If so, then he needs to put a check for NSNull Class. I will Modify it.

Comment: its not problem of null, the problem is when value is null then not add first comma and second one is if tag2 and tag3 is null not add & how to manage , and & character

Comment: Then you gotta apply some basic if-else and think properly and deeply on the permutations and combinations possible with the 3 Tags. Lay them out on a paper and prepare your conditional statements accordingly. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *getTags =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ , %@ & %@",[getSelectedArray valueForKey:@"tag1"] isEqual:[NSNull null] ? tag1:@"",[getSelectedArray valueForKey:@"tag2"] isEqual:[NSNull null] ? tag2:@"",[getSelectedArray valueForKey:@"tag3"] isEqual:[NSNull null] ? tag3:@""];
```